# sed inline not working to modify XML-style input

Tags: linux, bash, sed, xml

the problem is that I cannot put the complete command on a line with SED, I had already done it but with those file it does not work:
my exemple :

```
<file>Documents/time/text1</file> //2X slash + 2 words to remove !!
<file>Commun/text2</file>         //1X slash to remove + 1 words to remove
<file>Current/text3</file>        //1X slash to remove + 1 words to remove
```

Why does this code not work in line ?

```bash
sed 's/Documents//g' | sed 's/time//g' | sed 's/Commun//g' | sed 's/Current//g' | sed 's/Current//g' | sed '/<file>/s|<file>/|<file>|' | sed '/<file>/s|<file>/|<file>|' tracklist.txt > newtracklist.txt
```

Comment: Please provide your intended output.

Comment: please update the question with *a)* a textual description of what you're attempting to do (eg, retrieve the file *name*), *b)* the expected result (corresponding to the provided sample input) and *c)* details of what you mean by *`does not work`* ... (syntax) error? wrong output? hangs?

Comment: If the answer to "Why does this code not work in line?" isn't just "because you aren't calling `sed -i`" then [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "in line" and what exactly the problem is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

##### Given your input XML file

Added a `r` root node:

```
<r>
    <file>Documents/time/text1</file>
    <file>Commun/text2</file>
    <file>Current/text3</file> 
</r>
```

##### The code:

```
xidel --xquery '
    <r>{
        for $x in //file
        return <file>{tokenize($x, "/")[last()]}</file>
    }</r>
' --output-format=xml --output-node-indent file.xml
```

##### Yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
  <file>text1</file>
  <file>text2</file>
  <file>text3</file>
</r>
```

##### Explanations:

Here, instead of using the wrong tool: `sed`, I use `XPath` and `XQuery` (the former is a subset of the latter) proper `XML` parser.

[`xidel`](https://github.com/benibela/xidel) is the Swiss army knife for manipulating HTML/XML.

##### Usage:

```
xidel ... file.xml > new_file.xml
```

If you want to edit *on the fly*:

```
xidel ... file.xml | sponge file.xml
```

`sponge` from **GNU** `more-utils`.

Answer (score 1):

Running OP's current pipeline of `sed` scripts causes the contents of the input file (`tracklist.txt`) to be printed to stdout and then the pipeline hangs (ie, no other output, no return to a commnand prompt).  I'm *guessing* this is what OP is referring to when stating *`it does not work`* ... ??

Primary issue: the input file (`tracklist.txt`) needs to be provided as an argument to the 1st `sed` script and not as an argument to the last `sed` script.

Recommentation:

```
# instead of this:

sed 's/Documents//g'               | ... |  sed '/<file>/s|<file>/|<file>|' tracklist.txt
                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# do this:

sed 's/Documents//g' tracklist.txt | ... |  sed '/<file>/s|<file>/|<file>|'
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Running this updated version of OP's `sed` pipeline generates:

```
<file>text1</file>
<file>text2</file>
<file>text3</file>
```

---

While there are better tools for parsing HTML/XML, if OP must use `sed` then there are several ways to generate the same results but in a more efficient manner.

One idea requiring a single `sed` script:

```
sed -E 's|(<file>).*/([^/]+</file>)|\1\2|' tracklist.txt
```

Where:

- `-E` - enables support for extended regexes
- `(<file>)` - (1st capture group) matches the string `<file>`
- `([^/]+</file>)` - (2nd capture group) matches all characters that are not a `/` followed by the string `</file>`
- `.*/` - everything between the two capture groups ending in a `/`
- `\1\2` - replacement string consists of the two capture groups appended together
- **NOTE:** this works for the specific input provided by OP; it may need tweaking if the format of the input varies from what's shown in OP's sample input

For OP's sample input this generates:

```
<file>text1</file>
<file>text2</file>
<file>text3</file>
```

Comment: Nice, but OP use the wrong tool ^^ What if the closing tag is on a newline? This is would be a perfectly valid XML.

Comment: did you see the parts ... *`there are better tools for parsing HTML/XML, if OP must use sed`*  .... *`this works for the specific input provided by OP`*; there are a slew of ways this answer breaks if the format of OP's input differs from that provided in the sample, and OP will find out real quickly should they actually run into such a situation

Comment: thank a lot , have make a new script this work fine :                                                                                      sed -r 's/\b(Documents|time|Commun|Current|CurrentTitle)\b//g' tracklist1.txt | sed -E 's|(<file>).*/([^/]+</file>)|\1\2|' > newtracklist.txt

Comment: @AllanTori `-r` is the old GNU sed option that's now replaced by `-E`, don't mix them. You don't need 2 separate sed commands anyway though as `sed 'foo' | sed 'bar'` is usually equivalent to `sed 'foo; bar'`.

Comment: ok thank you , with -E this work perfect

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -MXML -e 'my  $xml = open-xml( $*ARGFILES.Str );
                  for $xml.elements( :RECURSE(0), :TAG{"file"} ) -> $E {
                      my $old = $E.contents[0];
                      my $new  = XML::Text.new( text => $old.text.match(/ <?after "/">  <-[/]>+  $/) );
                      $E.replace( $old, $new );
                  };  .say for $xml;'   file.xml
```

OR:

```perl
% raku -MXML -e 'my  $xml = open-xml( $*ARGFILES.Str );
                 for $xml.elements( :RECURSE(0), :TAG{"file"} ) -> $E {
                      my $old = $E.contents[0];
                      my $new  = XML::Text.new( text => $old.text.path.basename );
                      $E.replace( $old, $new );
                  };  .say for $xml;'   file.xml
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family that features high-level [Grammars](https://dev.to/jj/introduction-to-grammars-with-perl6-75e) for parsing text. Along with Raku/Rakudo itself, community members support modules in the Raku/Rakudo ecosystem. One of those modules is the ([Raku-native](https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML/blob/main/lib/XML/Grammar.rakumod)) `XML` module.

Similar to the OP's other question, in Raku with the `XML`-module you can (for example) limit replacements to 1). the top-level and 2). within only the `<file>` TAG. This is done by setting the code to iterate through `elements` with the limitations `:RECURSE(0), :TAG{"file"}`. FYI, you can iterate through all `TAG`s at all depths if so desired: simply set `:RECURSE(Inf)` and remove the `:TAG` named-argument, which sets the `:TAG` restriction to False.

The first answer above identifies suitable TAGs/levels for replacement. Thus identified, each element's internal (i.e. non-TAG) `contents[0]` are assigned to the variable `$old`, which is actually an `XML::Text` object. The `$old` object is `.text` extracted into a string, and the desired `match` is found. A new (`XML::Text.new`) object is created (`$new`) with the now-corrected `text => 'value'` key/value pair. From here the `XML`-module's `replace` routine completes the job: `replace( $old, $new )`.

The second answer above is a clever twist on the first. Because the OP wants to edit path names, routines associated with Raku's `IO::Path` object class can be used. Raku's `.IO` routine understands the text as a valid path name, and Raku's `.basename` routine returns the final filename. This approach has the potential to increase code portability, because Raku has mechanisms for using the correct (`/` or `\` ) path-separator on different platforms.

Sample Input (thanks to @GillesQuénot!):

```xml
<r>
    <file>Documents/time/text1</file>
    <file>Commun/text2</file>
    <file>Current/text3</file>
</r>
```

Sample Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><r>
    <file>text1</file>
    <file>text2</file>
    <file>text3</file>
</r>
```

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML
https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/Path
https://rakudo.org/
https://raku.org

Comment: Ah? I don't know Roku at all I will see this, it seems very interesting, thank you very much

Comment: Raku is the new name for the programming language formerly known as Perl6. It was re-named in 2019 to reduce confusion between the two sister languages in the Perl-family. You can find some interesting blogs/videos online. Feel free to check out the homepage ( https://raku.org ) and/or the subreddit ( https://www.reddit.com/r/rakulang/ ).